# ReferenceError: document is not defined in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I searched many solutions but didn't find how to solve  Server-side rendering(SSR) in ReactJs.
I'm using a font-picker-react after a successful install, it gives me an error, given below

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at D:\node\count-down\node_modules\@samuelmeuli\font-manager\dist\index.js:167:34
    at D:\node\count-down\node_modules\@samuelmeuli\font-manager\dist\index.js:2:68
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\count-down\node_modules\@samuelmeuli\font-manager\dist\index.js:5:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\node\count-down\node_modules\font-picker-react\dist\FontPicker.js:5:19)
```

Comment: We can't reproduce your error and thus can't help you. Please read how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing server side rendering, there's a good chance that the global window object is going to be undefined because that is only something the client will understand, so you cannot use window apis, that means `window.document` will be undefined.

So the place you are using `document`, you will have to check if `window.document` exists then only run that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

In SSR, `window` is generally not defined. Which means  `window?.document == null` case is needed to be handler either inside the component or by yourself.

You can use conditional rendering to decide whether to call `font-picker-react` Component or not

```
{ window.document ? <MyComponent /> : null }
```